# simcard not found emergency calls only

Tags: cyanogenmod

I am using samsung galaxy fame. When I flashed cm12 my phone is unable to detect simcard when i dialed *#*#4636#*#* i cannot even turn on radio there. When I chose option of preferred network it shows unknown.
The main problem is my phone shows imei number but unable to detect sim card .please help me and give me solutions over it .its my request.

Comment: Why don't you reflash the stock ROM. It is probable the flashing didn't go well or the ROM has issues. Is the ROM stable? Give us the link and the instructions you followed.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know whether the CM12 ROM you flashed was dedicated to that specific device – or maybe for another one. In the latter case, it might simply be not fully compatible with yours.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure your flashed it without getting erros and with compatible custom rom.
2. How can you turn of radio anyhow if it doesn't have any connectivity(radio off) ?
   3.Same, how can you even search networks if there is "no sim found" message?

Solution is flash it again and check that you are flashing with compatible rom.
Enjoy! This